# awk partial matching not being printed

Tags: awk, match, partial

```
awk -F"," -v var=$test '$1 ~ /^var$/{print}' alpha.txt
```

I tried hard-coding my var with my actual variable input and I found that this code works. However, when I tried for example `/^ppl$/` to search for partial match of apple, it does not display. can someone give me some guidance as to how I can parse my variable into the command?

Comment: `/^ppl$/` wouldn't give a partial match of apple, as you've required that the line consist only of `ppl`; the `^` means the start of the line and `$` means the end.

Comment: Thanks alot. may i know if i wish to get a partial match of for example apple day, how can i modify the code to do it?

Comment: Just use `ppl`; that places no restriction on where in the string the match may occur.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
awk -F"," -v var=$test '$1 ~ "^"var"$"' alpha.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. May i know if i wish to retreive any match with white spaces in the field, how could i do it?

Comment: @user1823986 you meant your `$test (var)` is `" "`? if you want to match **any** space, which means, it could be at beginning, endding or middle of the field. just `$1~var`

Comment: oh. Thanks alot. i think i mixed it up a little with my reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"," '$1 ~ /^'"$test"'$/{print}' alpha.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're anchoring the match at the beginning *and* the end, just use `==`

```
awk -F"," -v var=$test '$1 == var' alpha.txt
```

Unless `$test` contains a regular expression, in which case @Kent has the right answer.